# Java Jersey server not getting POST parameters

Tags: java, web-services, jersey, server-side, jersey-2.0

I am using Java Jersey on the server side and I am using a @BeanParam to collect the POST parameters via JSON, but the @BeanParam class is just not getting them.

The API:

```
@POST
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response sync(@BeanParam SyncRequestParams request) {
         .........
}
```

The @BeanParam class :

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class SyncRequestParams {
   @JsonProperty("id")
   private int id;
}
```

So if the client POSTs a JSON like:

```
{
  "id": 12345
}
```

The SyncRequestParams will still have id as 0, and not 12345

What did I not do right here?

Thanks
IS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@BeanParam` cannot be used to map a JSON payload to a bean.

[Using](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0-SNAPSHOT/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/BeanParam.html) `@BeanParam` requires the bean fields to be annotated with jax-rs param annotations (`@FormParam`, `@QueryParam`, etc.). The runtime then creates a bean and populates the fields with the param values. Since your `id` has no parameter annotation (and the request does not contain such a parameter) it is still 0.

What you want is that the JSON payload of the POST request is parsed to an instance of `SyncRequestParams` and therefore you should simply write

```
@POST
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response sync(SyncRequestParams request) {
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to annotate the fields of the class you want generated with `@FormParam` annotation:

```
public class SyncRequestParams {
   @FormParam("id")
   private int id;
}
```

see more detailed explanation [here](https://dzone.com/articles/new-jax-rs-20-%E2%80%93-beanparam)